# CppUTest on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cmake, ninja, cpputest

We use CppUTest to run unit tests.
This is being performed by Cmake/Ninja where after building the tests, we use ninja to execute them `ninja test`

an example output of this is:

```
1/3 Test #1: Test1...................................................   Passed    0.03 sec
      Start 2: Test2
2/3 Test #2: Test2.........................................................   Passed    0.00 sec
      Start 3: Test3
3/3 Test #3: Test3..............................................................***Exception: SegFault  0.00 sec

66% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 3

Total Test time (real) =   0.26 sec

The following tests FAILED:
     3 - Test3 (SEGFAULT)
Errors while running CTest
FAILED: CMakeFiles/test.util
```

This is ok if i trigger the build locally on my machine and analyze it manually. Now what i am looking for is an already existing solution to help jenkins analyze the output.

Right now, Jenkins executes the build and exits "successfully", because the command itself `ninja test` executed successfully, but not all of the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already found this but you can create a JUnit output with cpputest with the -ojunit output flag. Jenkins should then be able to import the results from this file.

[CppUTest Commandline Switches](https://cpputest.github.io/manual.html#command_line)